# What is the purpose of SO_REUSEADDR?

Tags: c, sockets, multicast, setsockopt

I am trying to understand a multicast code, and I don't understand the utilities of a little part :

```
int fd_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
u_int yes = 1;

setsockopt(fd_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

I don't understand the utilities of the `setsockopt` function. I understand that this function permits to modify the socket in the kernel, and `SOL_SOCKET` is because my modification is about the level of the socket and not of the level of a protocol. I don't understand `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For UDP sockets, setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` option allows multiple sockets to be open on the same port.

If those sockets are also joined to a multicast group, any multicast packet coming in to that group and port will be delivered to all sockets open on that port.